# Why are my Eclipse RCP mainMenu commands not clickable on mac?

Tags: macos, command, eclipse-rcp

In our Eclipse RCP project, we want to use commands in the top level of our main menu. So the OverviewCommand handler should be called, if you click on "Übersicht" like in the screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrtlq.png

That's our plugin.xml:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">

     <command
           commandId="at.ticketline.command.OverviewCommand"
           label="Übersicht"
           style="push">
     </command>

     <command
              commandId="at.ticketline.command.TicketCommand"
              label="Ticket">
     </command>
     <command
              commandId="at.ticketline.command.KundeCommand"
              label="Kunde">
     </command>
     <command
              commandId="at.ticketline.command.SucheCommand"
              label="Suche">
     </command>

     <command
              commandId="at.ticketline.command.ArtikelCommand"
              label="Artikel">
     </command>
  </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

On Windows it works, but not on mac. Could you imagine why? It also works when I put the commands into a "menu" tag, but then they would not be on the first level, and that's not what we want.

Thank you for every hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put SWT MenuItems reliably in the main menu bar, which is what you are trying to do with that menuContribution. Windows supports it.  Apparently Mac doesn't.  Eclipse and its user guidelines definitely don't recommend it.

The behaviour your want is more appropriate for the main toolbar.  Use  `toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar`, create a toolbar, and then place your commands inside.  If you don't have icons, you should get text.

Comment: Thank you very much, probably we will use the toolbar!

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you put the commands inside a menu?

Comment: No, they are inside menuContribution. You need to introduce a menu between menuContribution and command

Comment: That's a pity. In Windows it works without the menu-tag. Then the commands are called by a click on the labels. On mac, the commands are only displayed, but don't react on user interaction. Thanks anyway!